# Adding White Spaces after strings in pandas dataframe: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a new column based on the length of a string and adding whites spaces to end of the string.

```
data={ 'Fruit':['Apple','Mango','Watermelon'],
'Color':['Red','Yellow','Green']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['length']=df['Fruit'].str.len()
df['Fruit_color']=df.apply(lambda row: row['Fruit']+ (' '* row[length])+row['color'])
```

i get the error `“TypeError: string indices must be integers”?`

When i change the code only to this

```
df['white_space']=df.apply(lambda row:  (' '* row[length])) 
i get KeyError: ('length', 'occurred at index Fruit')
```

How do i avoid these errors to get the desired result

Regards,
Ren.

Comment: whats your desired output?

Comment: `apply(lambda row: ..., axis=1)`.

Comment: typo in `length`?  `df['lenght'] = ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do not need to use apply

```
df['Fruit']+ df['lenght'].map(lambda x : ' '*x)+df['Color']
Out[689]: 
0                Apple     Red
1             Mango     Yellow
2    Watermelon          Green
dtype: object
```

Fix your code : 1 type , 2 adding ''

```
df.apply(lambda row: row['Fruit']+ (' '* row['lenght'])+row['Color'],axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use `apply`:

```
df['Fruit_color'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Fruit'] + ' '*x['length'] + x['Color'], axis=1)
                                                            ^^                       ^^
```

Be careful of quoting column names, else Python will think you're calling a variable. Also be careful of spelling your variable names right, you used both `length` and `lenght`

Answer (score 1):

#### Comprehension

`zip(*map(df.get, df))` is another way to do `df.itertuples(index=False)`

```
[f'{f}{" " * l}{c}' for f, c, l in zip(*map(df.get, df))]

['Apple     Red', 'Mango     Yellow', 'Watermelon          Green']
```

​

As a new column

```
df.assign(New=[f'{f}{" " * l}{c}' for f, c, l in zip(*map(df.get, df))])

        Fruit   Color  length                        New
0       Apple     Red       5              Apple     Red
1       Mango  Yellow       5           Mango     Yellow
2  Watermelon   Green      10  Watermelon          Green
```

Without the need for an intermediate step of assigning `length`

```
df.assign(New=[f'{f}{" " * len(f)}{c}' for f, c in zip(df.Fruit, df.Color)])

        Fruit   Color                        New
0       Apple     Red              Apple     Red
1       Mango  Yellow           Mango     Yellow
2  Watermelon   Green  Watermelon          Green
```

Comment: Could you care to explain this part  please:`*map(df.get, df))` ? I almost understand it, but I'm not quite sure what it is doing

Comment: I added a blurb about it